# Add external API call to DRF serializer response

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Working with Django REST Framework, I need to consume multiple endpoints from an external API to seed my responses.

**models.py**

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manual = models.FileField(upload_to=machine_path)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class MachinesList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        client = request.user.customer_code
        _status, machines = get_machines(customer)  # 1st external request

        if (_status == 200):
            _machines = Machine.objects.filter(name__in=machines['message'])
            serializer = MachineSerializer(_machines, many=True)

            # for machine in machines['message']:
            #     _status2, information = get_machine_information(customer, machine)  # 2nd external request

            return Response(serializer.data, status=_status)

        else:
            return Response(machines, status=_status)
```

The external API endpoints return:
**1st endpoint**

```
{
  "message": [
    "ec1"
  ]
}
```

**2nd endpoint**

```
{
  "message": {
    "current_program": "PROG",
    "alarm": [
      "A001 - Watchdog",
      "A002 - Pressure"
    ],
    "status": "STOPPED",
    "kg/h": 0,
    "picks": 0,
    "time": "00:00:00"
  }
}
```

The problem here is how to seed serializer data with the second external API call for each object in my database.

Comment: What do you mean by seed serializer_data ?